# Ruby Errno::EADDRINUSE For Simple Socket Example

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm perplexed by some socket code using `IO.select` that doesn't cleanup after running:

```rb
require 'socket'

def run(socket)
  loop do
    begin
      selections, _, _ = IO.select([socket])
      io, _ = selections
      begin
        connection, _ = io.accept
        puts "ACCEPTED: #{connection.inspect}"
      ensure
        puts "CLOSING: #{connection.inspect}"
        connection.close
        puts "CLOSED: #{connection.inspect}"
      end
    rescue Interrupt
      puts "INTERRUPTED"
      break
    end
  end
end

begin
  socket = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
  socket.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(5000, '0.0.0.0'))
  socket.listen(4)
  puts "LISTENING: #{socket.inspect}"
  run(socket)
ensure
  puts "CLOSING: #{socket.inspect}"
  socket.close
  puts "CLOSED: #{socket.inspect}"
end
```

Running the program and sending an interrupt signal gives prints:

```
ruby script.rb 
LISTENING: #<Socket:fd 7>
^CINTERRUPTED
CLOSING: #<Socket:fd 7>
CLOSED: #<Socket:(closed)>
```

Running the program another time and making a request gives:

```
ruby script.rb 
LISTENING: #<Socket:fd 7>

curl 0.0.0.0:5000

ACCEPTED: #<Socket:fd 8>
CLOSING: #<Socket:fd 8>
CLOSED: #<Socket:(closed)>

curl: empty reply from server

^CINTERRUPTED
CLOSING: #<Socket:fd 7>
CLOSED: #<Socket:(closed)>
```

Despite the debug info seeming normal - quickly running the program again gives:

```
ruby script.rb
script.rb:25:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:5000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
from script.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

The socket eventually binds again (with a long pause in between runs). What isn't getting cleaned up? The logs make it seem like each call is getting cleaned up.

Comment: I don’t really know this stuff well enough to write a proper answer, but it looks like you are leaving connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state (there also appears to be a bug in the Mac implementation of `netstat` that means it isn’t showing those connections). You can fix it by adding `socket.setsockopt(:SOCKET, :REUSEADDR, true)` before the call to `bind`.

Comment: @matt - adding that fixes the problem. Now I'm a bit unclear if I am making a mistake in leaving the connections in `TIME_WAIT` - (or is this sort of thing unavoidable and everyone that does this sort of thing always enables `:REUSEADDR`). Thanks for the answer!